# IntelliJ IDEA Scala plugin turning off

Tags: plugins, scala, intellij-idea

I'm using Scala plugin for IntelliJ IDEA and my project has a few thousands lines of source code.

Unfortunatelly, when I'm typing the code IDE freezes frequently(i.e. on code completion etc.). I tried to switch off inspection, but there was no effect.

Is there a way to turning off all plugin's features for using it just as syntax highlighter and build tool?

Comment: Freeze situation usually happens when I'm trying to use plugin's help features like code completion or floating help-hints(when mouse cursor is on some code terminal and ctrl-key is pressed). This situation happens accidentally very often during the work. Actually these features don't used so often. It would be nice to turn them off for a while, and using IDE just as syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 7):

Try closing or reconfiguring all views that show detail at the level of individual class members (methods, vals and vars, basically). Specifically, that's the Structure view and the Project view when the "Show Members" option (in the "cogwheel" menu at the top right) is enabled. It is reported that maintaining these views slows the Scala plug-in appreciably.

You should also get the 9.0.4 EAP of IDEA (currently #95.538) and stay up-to-date with the Scala plug-in nightly releases. There sometimes bugs, but as a rule, quality is good and progress is sufficient to warrant doing this.

**Edit:**

The two views that do (or can) present information at the class member level of detail and which can slow the plug-in substantially are:

1. The Structure tool window (Window -> Tool Windows -> Structure / Alt+7)
2. The Project tool window (Window -> Tools Windows -> Project / Alt+1)

The Structure tool window always shows the class member level of detail, so if it's open, you're susceptible to this slow-down. The Project tool window only shows class members if you configure it to do so. The way this option is controlled is in the menu that is attached to the "cog wheel" or "gear" icon in that window's upper-right corner. The option to disable in that menu is "Show Members."

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Randall! Could you explain where is that views more detailed? I can't find such views in Settings or Project structure. What you mean by "Show Members"? Is it code style settings option, or inspection settings option or somthing else?

Comment: Other things I've tried/seen suggested for scala plugin/IDEA: increase heap, 32-bit JRE, enable CompressedOops, and then start messing with the gc generations. gdluck!

Comment: to Randall: Oh, I realized what you mean. Actually these two options were always disabled in my IDE, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem. Just now, I turned off the structure window and the problem immediately goes away.

Answer (score 2):

Try IDEA X EAP plugin version. It's much faster.